# (React Native) Fade in Text component only once

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a simple tagging feature. The user types in a word and when submitted, the text fades in inside another component. Currently, I'm sending all text input values into state array then re-rendering the array items whenever a new value is added to the array.

**The problem:**

The fade in animation happens to every tag whenever a new tag fades in, and the animation loops as I keep typing.

**What I'd like to happen:**

Each tag fades in once and remains visible.

This is my code so far:

**State**

```
 state = {
    allTags: []
  };
```

**Component**

```js
    class Tags extends React.Component {
      fadeIn = new Animated.Value(0);

      fadeInTag = () => {
        this.fadeIn.setValue(0);
        Animated.timing(this.fadeIn, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 600
        }).start();
      };

      render() {
        const animationStyles = {
          opacity: this.fadeIn
        };

        return (
          <View>
            {this.props.allTags.map(function(tag, i) {
              return (
                <Animated.Text
                  key={i}
                  style={[animationStyles, tagStyles.fadeStyle]}
                >
                  {tag}
                </Animated.Text>
              );
            }, this.fadeInTag())}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `Tags` will re-render every time you `setState` for `tags`. You should move that `Animated.Text` to separated component and use `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent re-render from changing props of them.

```
class FadeText extends PureComponent {
  fadeIn = new Animated.Value(0);

  componentDidMount(){
    Animated.timing(this.fadeIn, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }

  render(){
    const {tag} = this.props;
    return (
      <Animated.Text style={{ opacity: this.fadeIn }}>
        {tag}
      </Animated.Text>
    );
  }
}
```

An example is provided [here](https://snack.expo.io/@heligpfleigh/groaning-edamame)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know about Pure Components but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much and the example was super helpful :)!